# Collapse rows while merging other values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> head(df)
  Gene                                         Region
1 ANKS1B                      Brain...Hypothalamus
2 ANKS1B                          Brain...Amygdala
5 AXE2 Brain...Nucleus.accumbens..basal.ganglia.
6 AXE2           Brain...Putamen..basal.ganglia.
```

I want to turn it into this

```
> head(df)
  Gene                                               Region
1 ANKS1B              Brain...Hypothalamus, Brain...Amygdala
5 AXE2                Brain...Nucleus.accumbens..basal.ganglia., Brain...Putamen..basal.ganglia.
```

Essentially, I want to collapse rows in which the gene value is the same, and append the `Region`, separated by a ",". How can I do this? My dataframe is ~50,000 rows.

Comment: `aggregate(Region~Gene, df, toString)`

Comment: this works but deletes values which are not duplicated. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Yes, probably you need to add those variables in group too. `aggregate(Region~Gene + col1 + col2, df, toString)` If this is not what you want please update your post.